# State management issue with react ul contenteditable

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a custom form field that displays and edits string array as an editable `ul` list - the field creates a bullet for every string item in the array.

[image: list field]

The issue is when I try to manage the field's state with a `value` and `onChange` props (like a regular form field) - the field duplicates the values that are being displayed and as a result, it's also set the value with the duplicates.

This is a piece of code that reproduces the issue:

```js
import { useMemo, useState, type FormEvent } from 'react';

export default function List() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string[]>(['first line', 'second line']);
  const listItems = useMemo(
    () => Array.from(Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]),
    [value]
  );

  function handleInput(event: FormEvent) {
    const items = event.currentTarget.innerHTML
      .split(/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/)
      ?.map((item: string) => item.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, ''))
      ?.filter(Boolean);
    setValue(items);
  }

  return (
    <ul
      contentEditable
      suppressContentEditableWarning
      onInput={handleInput}
    >
      {listItems.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I use a local state to demonstrate the issue but in reality, the `value` and `onChange` will be injected as props

Some conclusions I've come to while playing with this:

1. There is a react inner state that manages the `ul` element inner HTML perfectly. A temporary solution I use is to call `onChange` on the `ul`'s `onBlur` event.
2. When I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and set the `li` as strings - The cursor jumps to the beginning of the list for every stroke and I can't set the cursor position because I don't have a reference to the current edited line - but that's an issue or another question

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use [react-contenteditable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable)

The EditableListField component takes in two props: value and onChange. value is an array of strings that represent the list items, and onChange is a function that updates the list items.
The EditableListField component maintains a state variable html that stores the HTML representation of the list.
When the value prop changes, the useEffect hook updates html to reflect the new list items.
The handleChange function is triggered when the user edits the list. It parses the updated HTML, extracts the list items, and calls the onChange prop with the new list items.

The App component maintains a state variable listItems that stores the current list items. It renders the EditableListField component and passes listItems and a setter function setListItems as props.

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState, useEffect, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";

interface EditableListFieldProps {
  value: string[];
  onChange: (newItems: string[]) => void;
}

const EditableListField: React.FC<EditableListFieldProps> = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const listHtml = value.map((item) => `<li>${item}</li>`).join("");
    setHtml(`<ul>${listHtml}</ul>`);
  }, [value]);

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(event.currentTarget.innerHTML, "text/html");
    const items = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll("li")).map(
      (li) => li.textContent || ""
    );
  
    onChange(items);
    setHtml(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  };
  

  return <ContentEditable html={html} onChange={handleChange} tagName="div" />;
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState<string[]>(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]);

  const handleListChange = (newItems: string[]) => {
    setListItems(newItems);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Editable List:</label>
      <EditableListField value={listItems} onChange={handleListChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you wanna play around with the [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-fx7xzj?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A37%2C53)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wanted to know if the issue I encountered is a known issue (with a workaround hopefully) or something I did wrong.  
I played with `react-contentediable` and I ran into issues when I used react@18 and function component and I also saw a bug when I press Enter form the list.